# Forward an email and append additional text without losing format of original message

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to forward an email that I received and append an additional message on top of it.   The following code I wrote kinda does this, but I lose all the formatting of the original message.  Is there any way to maintain the format of the original message and yet able to append additional test to the email?

MY CODE:

```
Sub xForward()
    myMessage = "You recently requested access to the table.   We are requiring all requests to complete a mandatory training session." & vbCr & vbCr & "Thank you, " & vbCr & "Ricky"

    Dim itmOld As MailItem, itmNew As MailItem

    Set itmOld = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set itmNew = itmOld.Forward

    itmNew.Body = myMessage & vbCr & vbCr & itmOld.Body
    itmNew.Subject = "Access Request"
    itmNew.Display

    Set itmOld = Nothing
    Set itmNew = Nothing
End Sub
```

If I don't update the body of itmNew, then I maintain the format of the original message.  The moment I update itmNew.Body, then itmOld.Body is written in simple text and I lose all the formatting.

Comment: Try updating `.HTMLBody` instead. You'll need slightly different syntax: `itmNew.HTMLBody = myMessage & "<br /><br />" & itmNew.HTMLBody`

Answer (score 0):

I think JP's comment points you in the right direction but I assume your questions results from limited knowledge of HTML.  This is not a complete tutorial on HTML but I hope it gets your started.

If you use Debug.Print to output .HTMLBody to the immediate window you will see something like:

> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html
>   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head>
>
> Lots of stuff here
>
> </head> <body>
>
> Lots of stuff here
>
> </body> </html>

You will only get "<!DOCTYPE html ... " if the package that created the message supports the XML version of HTML.  The minimum you should see is:

> <html><head> Lots of stuff here </head><body> Lots of
>   stuff here </body></html>

If you place your extra message in front or at the end of this then you are breaking the rules of HTML.  What happens will depend on how forgiving the receiver's email package is.  To conform to the rules of HTML, you must place your extra message somewhere between  "<body>" and "</body>".

If you look through a few messages, you will see how much they can vary.  Some will be black text on white, some white text on black with every variation in between.  Your message must be readable no matter what the message's authors have done.  My suggestion is you create a one cell table at the top and you set the font and background colours.  Try the following and then adapt it to your requirements:

```
Dim AddedMsg As String
Dim Pos As Long

' Create message to be inserted
' =============================
' Start a table with white background and blue text
AddedMsg = "<table border=0 width=""100%"" style=""Color: #0000FF"" bgColor=#FFFFFF>"
' Add row with single cell
AddedMsg = AddedMsg & "<tr><td><p>Cool stuff you must see!!</p></td></tr>"
' End table
AddedMsg = AddedMsg & "</table>"

' Code to add message once you have checked there is an HTML body    
'================================================================
Pos = InStr(1, LCase(.HTMLBody), "<body")
If Pos = 0 Then
  ' This should be impossible.
  Call MsgBox("<Body> element not found in HTML body", vbCritical)
  ' Code to handle impossible situation
End If
Pos = InStr(Pos, .HTMLBody, ">")
If Pos = 0 Then
  ' This should be impossible.
  Call MsgBox("Terminating > for <Body> element not found in HTML body", vbCritical)
  ' Code to handle impossible situation
End If
'Insert your message
.HTMLBody = Mid(.HTMLBody, 1, Pos) & AddedMsg & Mid(.HTMLBody, Pos + 1)
```